# Improve model performance on unseen data

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

**NOTE:** This question was first [posted](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/390312/217442) on a different SO forum but I received suggestions to move it here

---

This is a follow-up question to a [question I had previously posted on this forum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/385486/217442)
We conducted an experiment on 100 subjects and obtained a dataset that was used to train a machine learning model that works almost perfectly (we get a 99.99% accuracy) using cross-validation but fails miserably when test to new unseen data (we get only 39.8% accuracy). In detail, here is how we are testing our model:

1. Conduct an experiment (100 subjects) and recording physiological data (skin conductance and heart rate)
2. For each subject, compute the feature from the raw data (thus, we obtain 100 datasets with 25 features)
3. Reserve the whole data of one subject for model validation
4. Combine the remaining 99 datasets into one large dataset (thus, we obtain a dataset with up to 1 million rows and 25 columns)
5. The obtained large dataset is used to train a model and evaluate it using a 10-folds cross-validation.
6. Use the reserved dataset (see step 3) to validate the model obtained in step 5 above
   The model performs very well (99.9% accuracy) when we used cross-validation (step 5) but fails to generalize (only 40% accuracy) when tested on new data from the unseen subject (step 3).

   ---

After [reading the comments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/385495/217442) I received in my previous question, I decided to revise how I validate the model. Thus, instead of removing all the sample of one subject (as I did in step 3), I only remove all but a few samples (just 0.1% of the sample, i.e around 100 samples in my case). Surprising the model performs significantly better and achieves a 90% accuracy. This is puzzling and I would like to ask a few questions:

(1)How can one explain that a few samples (just 100 samples) are responsible for such an increase in performance (from 40% to 90% accuracy)(I will need to publish my result in a reputable conference)?

(2) Is there any published work that discusses this type of phenomena?

Comment: Try Hyperparameter tuning of the model.

Comment: Really? As if that's supposed to produce State of the Art results?

Comment: if I got the question correctly, then previously you separated completely a class and there were no instances of that in the training? In that case your model didn't really see it coming and you evaluated on that.... Instead in the second case, you sampled your data; that means you now have your model the capacity to learn for that particular class as well and hence the performance boost... A better validation set would be a sample from all the classes! I hope this helps :)

Comment: @Aditya yes, that's exactly how I did it. However, I believe your last suggestion is exactly what I am trying not to do. I want to evaluate how the model would perform if evaluated on a new subject it has never seen before. In this case, it is underperforming and I would like to know how to improve it. Either way, thanks for your comment.

Comment: You are overfitting plain and simple. Your first method of getting a test set is the correct way to measure expected performance in the real world. Don’t listen to the suggestions to add in some of your test subjects data to the train set. Will you get to do that when the model is deployed? No, you will not.

Comment: @kbrose this cannot be overfitting if the performance is good when using a cross-validation (I used a 10 fold cross-validation and the std between the various folds is small)

Comment: It is overfitting. Showing the model data from the subject allows it to *over* fit to that subject.

Comment: @kbrose thanks for the clarification. I believe this is the case as well. However, could we call that overfitting or that the model has a high generalization error? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalization_error